# Unity3D Stop counter

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a script for a game that counts the playtime. So the question is how can i stop the script befor the game is over or for example save the time as a float.

```
    // Für die SpielZeit
    SpielZeit += Time.deltaTime;
    // SpielZeitText = Spielzeit in einen String + "Sekunden"
    SpielZeitText.text = " " + Mathf.Round(SpielZeit).ToString() + " " + "Sekunden";
    // SpielZeitFuerEscape = Spielzeit in einen String + "Sekunden" (für den escape canvas)
    SpielZeitFuerEscape.text = " " + Mathf.Round(SpielZeit).ToString() + " " + "Sekunden";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpielZeit`, `SpielZeitText`, and `SpielZietFuerEscape` should be put as members of the main class. Or you should set it accessible to anything which needs it.
Then put the counter in an `Update` function. (If you want to make a frame-by-frame update, include the `.text` setters there as well.) Enclose the counter with an if statement, which sees if you want to continue it, or if you want to stop it.

```
if(go_on) { //if the counter should keep going
    // Für die SpielZeit
    SpielZeit += Time.deltaTime;

     // SpielZeitText = Spielzeit in einen String + "Sekunden"
    SpielZeitText.text = " " + Mathf.Round(SpielZeit).ToString() + " " + "Sekunden";

    // SpielZeitFuerEscape = Spielzeit in einen String + "Sekunden" (für den escape canvas)
    SpielZeitFuerEscape.text = " " + Mathf.Round(SpielZeit).ToString() + " " + "Sekunden";
}
```

where `go-on` is a boolean, telling the code whether it should continue (`true`) or stop (`false`).

Comment: Actually do not use deltaTime.  deltaTime is frame rate dependent, is count frames not time.  You should use `Time.time` or `Time.relatimeSinceStartup`  See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html

Comment: But deltaTime tells you how long it took for the previous frame to reach the next frame, at least in Unity 5, 2018, 2019 So it would be pretty accurate when you use deltaTime for a counter.

Comment: Correct. It's definitely what you want to use when implementing a counter.  But to track how long you have been playing the game, you want one of the others.